# Redefining \listoffigures and \listoftables as tables

Tags: tables, table-of-contents

A friend of mine is required by his faculty to format his lists of figures (= "Abbildungsverzeichnis") and tables (= "Tabellenverzeichnis") as shown in the picture below. Is there a way to realize this by redefining the respective commands in `LaTeX`? Besides the caption (~ "Kurzüberschrift") the source (= "Quelle") needs to be included in the lists as well. [image: Abbildungsverzeichnis = list of figures, Tabellenverzeichnis = list of tables]

I've prepared this MWE as a start – it's far away from the desired result though.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{mwe}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics{example-image}
\caption{An awesome image. Source: Thatoneguy, W. (2003)}  
\end{figure}

\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline
Foo & Bar\\ \hline
Meh & More meh \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{An awesome table. Source: Someone, A. (2012)}
\end{table}

\listoffigures 

\listoftables

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Update: The version with `hyperref` is at the bottom of this post.

The question is some months old but here is a `tabular` approach by adding code to the `\caption` command and using separate files `\jobname.tof` and `\jobname.tot` and `\tableoffigures` and `\tableoftables` instead of `\listoffigures` and `\listoftables`, i.e. I kept the standard `\listof...` commands untouched.

The usual `\caption` command has been extended by a 4th optional argument holding the source of the figure or table and defaults to `Eigene Darstellung` (→ `own work`)

The `\@starttof` (start table of ...) command uses a `longtable` wrapper for the table to be displayed and provides for page breaks. The format of the table might have to be changed to the real specifications.

The crucial entries are given by `\writetoffile` and `\writetotfile` (with some more efforts, the might be just one command`)

A similar question (with other setup) can be found here: [I need to display \listoffigures as a table](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/363902/i-need-to-display-listoffigures-as-a-table)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[lmargin=1.5cm,rmargin=1.5cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{biblatex}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{letltxmacro}
\usepackage{xparse}

\addbibresource{biblio.bib}

\newcounter{fullfigurecounter}
\newcounter{fulltablecounter}

\makeatletter


\def\@starttof#1#2{%
  \begingroup
  \makeatletter
  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
  % Table format may be changed%%%
  \begin{longtable}{|p{2cm}|p{6cm}|p{7cm}|}
    \hline
    \multicolumn{3}{c}{}\tabularnewline
    \multicolumn{3}{c}{\Large \bfseries #2}\tabularnewline
    \multicolumn{3}{c}{}\tabularnewline
    \hline
    \multicolumn{3}{c}{}\tabularnewline[0.5ex]
    \hline
    \large Nummer  & \large Kurz\"uberschrift & \large Quelle \tabularnewline
    \hline
    \endhead % Repeating head
    \@input{\jobname.#1}%  Input the ToF or ToT file 
    \tabularnewline
  \hline
  \end{longtable}
  \setcounter{table}{0}%
  \if@filesw
  \expandafter\newwrite\csname tf@#1\endcsname
  \immediate\openout \csname tf@#1\endcsname \jobname.#1\relax
  \fi
  \endgroup
}



\newcommand{\tableoffigures}{%
  \cleardoublepage
  \@starttof{tof}{Abbildungs- und Quellenverzeichnis}
}%


\newcommand{\tableoftables}{%
  \clearpage
  \@starttof{tot}{Tabellenverzeichnis}%
}%


\def\temp@@a{figure}%
\def\temp@@b{table}%

\LetLtxMacro\captionpkg@caption\caption

\newcommand{\writetofline}[3]{%
  \ifnum\value{fullfigurecounter} > 1
  \tabularnewline
  \protect\hline
  \fi
  \figurename\ #1 & #2 & #3 
}

\newcommand{\writetotline}[3]{%
  \ifnum\value{fulltablecounter} > 1
  \tabularnewline
  \protect\hline
  \fi
  \tablename\ #1 & #2 & #3 
}


\RenewDocumentCommand{\caption}{somO{Eigene Darstellung}}{%
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}{%
    \captionpkg@caption{#3}%
  }{%
    \ifx\@currenvir\temp@@a
    \stepcounter{fullfigurecounter}%
    \else
    \ifx\@currenvir\temp@@b
    \stepcounter{fulltablecounter}%
    \fi
    \fi
    \IfValueTF{#2}{%
      \captionpkg@caption[#2]{#3}%
      \ifx\@currenvir\temp@@a
      \addtocontents{tof}{\writetofline{\thefigure}{#2}{#4}}%
      \else
      \ifx\@currenvir\temp@@b
      \addtocontents{tot}{\writetotline{\thetable}{#2}{#4}}%
      \fi
      \fi
    }{%
      \captionpkg@caption{#3}%
      \ifx\@currenvir\temp@@a
      \addtocontents{tof}{\writetofline{\thefigure}{#3}{#4}}%
      \else%
      \ifx\@currenvir\temp@@b
      \addtocontents{tot}{\writetotline{\thetable}{#3}{#4}}%
      \fi
      \fi
    }%
  }%
}




\makeatother

\usepackage{pgffor}
\begin{document}

\tableoffigures
\clearpage
\tableoftables
\clearpage

\foreach \x in {1,...,20} {%
  \begin{figure}
    \caption{Irgendein Bild}
  \end{figure}
  \begin{figure}
  \caption[Die Sonnenblumen]{Irgendein Bild}[Vincent van Gogh]
  \end{figure}
}
\clearpage

\foreach \x in {1,...,6} {%
  \begin{table}
    \caption[A nice table]{A nice table}[Me!]
  \end{table}
}

\clearpage

\foreach \x in {1,...,20} {%
  \begin{figure}
  \caption[Impressionen]{Impressions du Soleil}[Monet]
  \end{figure}
}


\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

The `biblio.bib` file is included in every TeX distribution.

[image]

**Update** (Due to request for 4th column holding the page number)

Additionally, `hyperref` is supported now as well

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[lmargin=1.5cm,rmargin=1.5cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{biblatex}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{letltxmacro}
\usepackage{xparse}

\newif\ifhyperrefloaded

\addbibresource{biblio.bib}

\newcounter{fullfigurecounter}
\newcounter{fulltablecounter}

\usepackage[hypertexnames=true]{hyperref}

\makeatletter

\@ifpackageloaded{hyperref}{\hyperrefloadedtrue}{\hyperrefloadedfalse}

\newcommand{\PhantomSection}{%
  \ifhyperrefloaded
  \phantomsection%
  \fi
}


\def\@starttof#1#2{%
  \begingroup
  \makeatletter
  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
  % Table format may be changed%%%
  \renewcommand{\theHtable}{longtable.\theLT@tables}% Use a different Hyperref name for table due the \refstepcounter{table}- issue with longtable
  \begin{longtable}{|p{2cm}|p{6cm}|p{5.5cm}|>{\raggedleft}p{1cm}|}
    \hline
    \multicolumn{4}{c}{}\tabularnewline
    \multicolumn{4}{c}{\Large \bfseries #2}\tabularnewline
    \multicolumn{4}{c}{}\tabularnewline
    \hline
    \multicolumn{4}{c}{}\tabularnewline[0.5ex]
    \hline
    \large Nummer  & \large Kurz\"uberschrift & \large Quelle & Seite \tabularnewline
    \hline
    \endhead % Repeating head
    \@input{\jobname.#1}%  Input the ToF or ToT file 
    \tabularnewline
  \hline
  \end{longtable}
  \setcounter{table}{0}%
  \if@filesw
  \expandafter\newwrite\csname tf@#1\endcsname
  \immediate\openout \csname tf@#1\endcsname \jobname.#1\relax
  \fi
  \endgroup
}


\newcommand{\tofiguresname}{Abbildungs- und Quellenverzeichnis}
\newcommand{\totablesname}{Tabellenverzeichnis}


\newcommand{\tableoffigures}{%
  \cleardoublepage
  \PhantomSection%
  \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\tofiguresname}%
  \@starttof{tof}{\tofiguresname}
}%


\newcommand{\tableoftables}{%
  \clearpage
  \PhantomSection%
  \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\totablesname}%
  \@starttof{tot}{\totablesname}%
}%


\def\temp@@a{figure}%
\def\temp@@b{table}%

\LetLtxMacro\captionpkg@caption\caption

\newcommand{\writetofline}[4]{%
  \ifnum\value{fullfigurecounter} > 1
  \tabularnewline
  \protect\hline
  \fi
  \figurename\ #1 & #2 & #3 &
  \ifhyperrefloaded 
  \protect\hyperlink{figure.\thefigure}{#4}%
  \else
  #4%
  \fi
}

\newcommand{\writetotline}[4]{%
  \ifnum\value{fulltablecounter} > 1
  \tabularnewline
  \protect\hline
  \fi
  \tablename\ #1 & #2 & #3 & 
  \ifhyperrefloaded 
  \protect\hyperlink{table.\thetable}{#4}%
  \else
  #4%
  \fi
}


\RenewDocumentCommand{\caption}{somO{Eigene Darstellung}}{%
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}{%
    \captionpkg@caption{#3}%
  }{%
    \ifx\@currenvir\temp@@a
    \stepcounter{fullfigurecounter}%
    \else
    \ifx\@currenvir\temp@@b
    \stepcounter{fulltablecounter}%
    \fi
    \fi
    \IfValueTF{#2}{%
      \captionpkg@caption[#2]{#3}%
      \ifx\@currenvir\temp@@a
      \addtocontents{tof}{\writetofline{\thefigure}{#2}{#4}{\thepage}}%
      \else
      \ifx\@currenvir\temp@@b
      \addtocontents{tot}{\writetotline{\thetable}{#2}{#4}{\thepage}}%
      \fi
      \fi
    }{%
      \captionpkg@caption{#3}%
      \ifx\@currenvir\temp@@a
      \addtocontents{tof}{\writetofline{\thefigure}{#3}{#4}{\thepage}}
      \else%
      \ifx\@currenvir\temp@@b
      \addtocontents{tot}{\writetotline{\thetable}{#3}{#4}{\thepage}}%
      \fi
      \fi
    }%
  }%
}




\makeatother

\usepackage{pgffor}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\clearpage

\tableoffigures
\clearpage
\tableoftables
\clearpage

\section{A section}


\foreach \x in {1,...,20} {%
  \begin{figure}
    \caption{Irgendein Bild}[\cite{Lam94}]
  \end{figure}
  \begin{figure}
    \caption[Die Sonnenblumen]{Irgendein Bild}[Vincent van Gogh]
  \end{figure}
}
\clearpage

\foreach \x in {1,...,6} {%
  \begin{table}
    \caption[A nice table]{A nice table}[Me!]
  \end{table}
}

\clearpage

\foreach \x in {1,...,20} {%
  \begin{figure}
  \caption[Impressionen]{Impressions du Soleil}[Monet]
  \end{figure}
}


\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you Christian, this is a really good solution :) I'm sorry that I didn't include it in the initial question but is there a way to include a column for the page number as well?

Comment: @JKR: I've  updated the example with `pagenumber` column and (optionally, `hyperref` support)

Comment: As soon as possible, I'll try to improve the hyperref version