# Fancy List of Figures layout/design

Tags: table-of-contents, floats, captions, subfloats, tocloft

do you see a chance to design the "List of Figures" pages in a way such that it looks more fancy? I fiddled around for days now but could not find an example or good solution, not even with `tocloft`, to get what I dream of. I know - in case it is even possible - it would be a lot of effort.

This is ideally what I would like to have (even a step in this direction would be great):
[image: Goal]

This is where I am stuck:

[image: stete-of-the-art]

Related minimal example code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}

    % add "Fig." before number in caption
    \usepackage[labelfont=bf]{caption}
    \renewcommand{\figurename}{Fig.}

    % add "Fig." before number in lof
    \usepackage{tocloft}
    \newlength{\mylen}
    \renewcommand*\cftfigpresnum{Fig.~}
    \settowidth{\mylen}{\cftfigpresnum\cftfigaftersnum}
    \addtolength{\cftfignumwidth}{\mylen}

    % command for thumbnails
    \newif\iflofimage
    \DeclareRobustCommand*{\lofimage}[2][]{%
        \iflofimage
        \includegraphics[{height=2.5em,keepaspectratio=true,#1}]{#2}
        \fi
        \ignorespaces }

\begin{document}

% columned lof
\lofimagetrue
\twocolumn
\begingroup
\let\onecolumn\twocolumn
\listoffigures
\endgroup
\onecolumn
\lofimagefalse

% body
Lorem

\begin{figure}[ht]
\label{a}\centering
\includegraphics{figure.jpg}
\caption[\lofimage{figure.jpg}Lorem ipsum dolor]{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing.}
\end{figure}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing.\newpage

\begin{figure}[ht]
\label{b}\centering
\includegraphics{figure.jpg}
\caption[\lofimage{figure.jpg}consetetur sadipscing.]{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing.}
\end{figure}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing.\newpage

\begin{figure}[ht]
\label{c}\centering
\includegraphics{figure.jpg}
\caption[\lofimage{figure.jpg}sit amet]{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing.}
\end{figure}

Lorem
\end{document}
```

Comment: Difficult, but should be possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only a preliminary version, I've to add the `hyperref` support etc. and other features. (Basically it's similar to my answer to this question here: 
[Redefining \listoffigures and \listoftables as tables](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/263979/redefining-listoffigures-and-listoftables-as-tables) )
The principal idea is to put all the `caption` images into a `tcolorbox` raster (a table would do as well, I think) -- please note, that currently the `list of tables` would get `tcolorbox` stuff as well! ;-)

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{letltxmacro}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{hyperref}

    % add "Fig." before number in caption
\usepackage[labelfont=bf]{caption}
\renewcommand{\figurename}{Fig.}

% add "Fig." before number in lof
\usepackage{tocloft}
\newlength{\mylen}
\renewcommand*\cftfigpresnum{Fig.~}
\settowidth{\mylen}{\cftfigpresnum\cftfigaftersnum}
\addtolength{\cftfignumwidth}{\mylen}

    % command for thumbnails
\newif\iflofimage
\DeclareRobustCommand*{\lofimage}[2][]{%
  \iflofimage
  \includegraphics[{height=2.5em,keepaspectratio=true,#1}]{#2}
  \fi
  \ignorespaces 
}


\makeatletter
\LetLtxMacro\captionpkg@caption\caption


\def\@starttof#1#2{%
  \begingroup
  \makeatletter
  \begin{tcbraster}[raster columns=3, raster equal height]
    \@input{\jobname.#1}%  Input the ToF or ToT file 
  \end{tcbraster}
  \if@filesw
  \expandafter\newwrite\csname tf@#1\endcsname
  \immediate\openout \csname tf@#1\endcsname \jobname.#1\relax
  \fi
  \endgroup
}

\newcommand{\tofiguresname}{\contentsname}


\newcommand{\tableoffigures}{%
  \cleardoublepage
  \chapter*{\tofiguresname}
  \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\tofiguresname}%
  \@starttof{tof}{\tofiguresname}
}%

\newtcolorbox{lofbox}[1][]{enhanced jigsaw, sharp corners, colback={white!70!black},#1}

\newcommand{\writetofline}[3]{%
  \protect\begin{lofbox}
    #1

    \par
    \figurename\ #2
    \protect\end{lofbox}
}



\RenewDocumentCommand{\caption}{som}{%
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}{%
    \captionpkg@caption{#3}%
  }{%
    \IfValueTF{#2}{%
      \captionpkg@caption[#2]{#3}%
      \addtocontents{tof}{\writetofline{#2}{\thefigure}{\thepage}}%
    }{%
      \captionpkg@caption{#3}%
      \addtocontents{tof}{\writetofline{#2}{\thefigure}{\thepage}}%
    }%
  }%
}

\lofimagetrue


\makeatother


\begin{document}

\tableoffigures

\clearpage

Lorem

\begin{figure}[ht]
\label{a}\centering
\includegraphics{beeduck.jpg}
\caption[\lofimage{beeduck.jpg}Lorem ipsum dolor]{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing.}
\end{figure}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing.\newpage

\begin{figure}[ht]
\label{b}\centering
\includegraphics{beeduck.jpg}
\caption[\lofimage{beeduck.jpg}consetetur sadipscing.]{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing.}
\end{figure}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing.\newpage

\begin{figure}[ht]
\label{c}\centering
\includegraphics{beeduck.jpg}
\caption[\lofimage{beeduck.jpg}sit amet]{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing.}
\end{figure}

Lorem
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Update**

I've used the ideas by the O.P. concerning the overlay and added it to the `lofbox` settings.

The `\includegraphics` command now stores the name of the the current file and will provide it as a thumbnail file -- there's no need to add it by hand to the `\caption[]{}` command.

Some optional arguments for the `lofbox` and graphics settings are still missing right now.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{letltxmacro}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{xpatch}

% add "Fig." before number in caption
\usepackage[labelfont=bf]{caption}
\renewcommand{\figurename}{Fig.}

\usepackage{hyperref}




\makeatletter
\newif\iflofimage
\newif\ifhyperrefloaded

\@ifpackageloaded{hyperref}{\hyperrefloadedtrue}{\hyperrefloadedfalse}

\newcommand{\PhantomSection}{%
  \ifhyperrefloaded
  \phantomsection%
  \fi
}



\LetLtxMacro\captionpkg@caption\caption

\def\nextthumbnailfile{}%


\LetLtxMacro\graphicx@@includegraphics\includegraphics%

\RenewDocumentCommand{\includegraphics}{O{}m}{%
  \def\nextthumbnailfile{#2}%
  \graphicx@@includegraphics[#1]{#2}%
}


\def\@starttof#1#2{%
  \begingroup
  \makeatletter
  \begin{tcbraster}[raster columns=3, raster equal height]
    \@input{\jobname.#1}%  Input the ToF or ToT file 
  \end{tcbraster}
  \if@filesw
  \expandafter\newwrite\csname tf@#1\endcsname
  \immediate\openout \csname tf@#1\endcsname \jobname.#1\relax
  \fi
  \endgroup
}

\newcommand{\tofiguresname}{\contentsname}


\newcommand{\tableoffigures}{%
  \cleardoublepage
  \PhantomSection%
  \chapter*{\tofiguresname}
  \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\tofiguresname}%
  \@starttof{tof}{\tofiguresname}
}%

\newtcolorbox{lofbox}[2][]{enhanced jigsaw, 
  sharp corners, 
  colback={white!70!black},
  boxsep=0.5em,
  left=0em,
  right=0em,
  top=0em,
  bottom=0em,
  boxrule=0em,
  overlay={\node[text=black,fill={white!90!black}, draw=white, line width=1mm, inner sep=1.5mm, anchor = north west] at (9.4em,1.4em) {#2};},
  #1
}


\newcommand{\writetofline}[4]{%
  \protect\begin{lofbox}{#4}
    \includegraphics[height=9em, width=9.5em,keepaspectratio=true]{#1}%

    \ifhyperrefloaded 
    \protect\hyperlink{figure.#3}{\figurename~#3}%

    #2%
    \else
    \figurename~#3%

    #2%
    \fi
    \protect\end{lofbox}
}


\def\temp@@a{figure}%

\RenewDocumentCommand{\caption}{som}{%
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}{%
    \captionpkg@caption{#3}%
  }{%
    \IfValueTF{#2}{%
      \captionpkg@caption[#2]{#3}%
      \iflofimage
      \ifx\@currenvir\temp@@a
      \hypertarget{figure.\number\value{figure}}{}%
      \addtocontents{tof}{\writetofline{\nextthumbnailfile}{#2}{\number\value{figure}}{\thepage}}%
      \fi
      \fi
    }{%
      \captionpkg@caption{#3}%
      \iflofimage
      \ifx\@currenvir\temp@@a
      \hypertarget{figure.\thefigure}{}%
      \addtocontents{tof}{\writetofline{\nextthumbnailfile}{#3}{\number\value{figure}}{\thepage}}%
      \fi
      \fi
    }%
  }%
}

\lofimagetrue


\makeatother


\begin{document}

\tableoffigures

\clearpage

Lorem

\begin{figure}[ht]
\label{a}\centering
\includegraphics{beeduck.jpg}
\caption[Lorem ipsum dolor]{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing.}
\end{figure}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing.
\clearpage

\begin{figure}[ht]
\label{b}\centering
\includegraphics{beeduck.jpg}
\caption[consetetur sadipscing.]{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing.}
\end{figure}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing.\clearpage

\begin{figure}[ht]
\label{c}\centering
\includegraphics{beeduck.jpg}
\caption[sit amet]{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing.}
\end{figure}

Lorem
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I'll return to this later on

Comment: @Martin: Welcome to the Dark Side of the Force;-) I'll try to improve my first version, but I am right occupied for an hour or so.

Comment: I am also working on it, here is my progress: in thumbnail definition, replace `\includegraphics[{height=9em, width=9.5em,keepaspectratio=true,#1}]{#2}\par\textbf{Fig.~\thefigure}`. In tcolorbox options add `boxsep=0.5em,left=0em,right=0em,top=0em,bottom=0em,boxrule=0em`

Comment: i got the page number to the right bottom: add `{#3}` as an argument to the lofbox environment in the writetofline definition, and then add a node to the tcolorbox with `\newtcolorbox{lofbox}[1]{..., overlay={\node[text=black,fill={white!90!black}, draw=white, line width=1mm, inner sep=1.5mm, anchor = north west] at (9.4em,1.4em) {#1}; }}`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34019/discussion-between-martin-and-christian-hupfer).