# Generating a table with all entries from all over the document

Tags: tables, macros, write

We're working on a technical document where we define messages in different chapter/section all over the document. All messages have the same structure and are displayed in a table. We thought that it would be nice to have a list with all these messages at the end of the document.

So I started working on a solution, that all table entries get stored in a separate file, which will be included at the end of the document.

This is my working solution:

```
\documentclass{article}
\RequirePackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{longtable, colortbl,environ}

\NewEnviron{tbl}
{%
\begin{longtable}{|p{2cm}|p{2cm}|p{2cm}|p{2cm}|}%
\hline\rowcolor[gray]{.8}%
Column 1 & Column 2 & Column 3 & Column 4\\\hline%
\endhead%
\BODY%
\end{longtable}%
}

\newwrite\mytabularwrite
\newcommand{\writetotablefile}[1]{\immediate\write\mytabularwrite{\unexpanded{#1}}}

\newcommand{\myrow}[4]{\writetotablefile{\unexpanded{#1&#2&#3&#4\\\hline}}%
#1&#2&#3&#4\\\hline%
}

\AtBeginDocument{\immediate\openout\mytabularwrite=\jobname-table.tex}
\AtEndDocument{}

\begin{document}

\section{Table 1}
\begin{tbl}
\myrow{1äöü€}{2}{3}{4}
\end{tbl}

\section{Table 2}
\begin{tbl}
\myrow{5}{6}{7}{8}
\end{tbl}

\section{Complete Table}

\begin{tbl}
% ATTENTION: Starting with that point here: don't use \myrow anymore! Temp. file is already closed.
\immediate\closeout\mytabularwrite
\input{\jobname-table}
\end{tbl}

\end{document}
```

The problem, I had to solve, was that (La)TeX cannot write text in append mode to a file. I found workarounds like: reading the tempfile, add my new data, store tempfile, repeat... But I think that is not efficient.

I now open the tempfile with the begin of the document and close it before including the tempfile for the final table.

Ok, I have a working solution, where's the problem? There currently is no problem. But I would like to ask, if there is a better way solving that problem.

Bye & thx,
aronadaal

Comment: A `list of ...` would be easier, I think!

Comment: I already thought about that. Is there a way to generate a `list of` with a structured information like the message, that consists of 4 parts?

Comment: if your list is at the end rather than the beginning then you don't necessarily need a file at all you could just save it in a macro, depends on memory constraints but that is not usually too much of a problem these days.

Comment: Yes, I've done this

Comment: @aronadaal: see for example my answer here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/263979/redefining-listoffigures-and-listoftables-as-tables

Answer (score 3):

Using a `ToC` - like approach has the advantage that the file can be included at any time in the document, but only once.

As usual with `ToC` and `longtable`: Compile more than once!

```
\documentclass{article}
\RequirePackage{fontspec}


\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{longtable, colortbl,environ}



\makeatletter


\def\@starttof#1#2{%
  \begingroup
  \makeatletter
  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
  % Table format may be changed%%%
  \begin{longtable}{|*{4}{p{2cm}|}}
    \hline\rowcolor[gray]{.8}%
    Column 1 & Column 2 & Column 3 & Column 4\\\hline%
    \endhead%

    \@input{\jobname.#1}%
  \end{longtable}
  \if@filesw
  \expandafter\newwrite\csname tf@#1\endcsname
  \immediate\openout \csname tf@#1\endcsname \jobname.#1\relax
  \fi
  \endgroup
}



\newcommand{\listofstuff}{%
  \@starttof{stuff}{}%
}



\NewEnviron{tbl}
{%
\begin{longtable}{|*{4}{p{2cm}|}}
  \hline\rowcolor[gray]{.8}%
  Column 1 & Column 2 & Column 3 & Column 4\\\hline%
  \endhead%
  \BODY%
\end{longtable}%
}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\tablerow}[4]{%
  #1&#2&#3&#4 \\ 
  \hline
}


\newcommand{\myrow}[4]{%
  \addtocontents{stuff}{\tablerow{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}}
  #1&#2&#3&#4\\\hline%
}


\begin{document}
\section{Table 1}
\begin{tbl}
\myrow{1äöü€}{2}{3}{4}
\end{tbl}

\section{Table 2}
\begin{tbl}
\myrow{5}{6}{7}{8}
\end{tbl}

\section{Complete Table}

\listofstuff

\end{document}
```

**Improved version**

```
\documentclass{article}
\RequirePackage{fontspec}


\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{environ}


\newcommand{\foo}{Some stuff}
\newcommand{\foobar}{Other stuff}

\makeatletter


\NewDocumentCommand{\@starttof}{smO{}}{%
  \begingroup
  \makeatletter
  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}{%
    \section*{#3}%
  }{%
    \section{#3}%
  }%
%  Table format may be changed%%%
  \begin{longtable}{|*{4}{p{2cm}|}}
    \hline\rowcolor[gray]{.8}%
    Column 1 & Column 2 & Column 3 & Column 4\\
    \hline%
    \endhead%
    \@input{\jobname.#2}%
  \end{longtable}
  \if@filesw
  \expandafter\newwrite\csname tf@#2\endcsname
  \immediate\openout \csname tf@#2\endcsname \jobname.#2\relax
  \fi
  \endgroup
}



\NewDocumentCommand{\listofstuff}{sO{Complete Table}}{%
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}{%
    \@starttof*{stuff}[#2]%
  }{%
    \@starttof{stuff}[#2]%
  }%
}



\NewEnviron{tbl}
{%
  \begin{longtable}{|*{4}{p{2cm}|}}
    \hline\rowcolor[gray]{.8}%
    Column 1 & Column 2 & Column 3 & Column 4\\\hline%
  \endhead%
  \BODY%
\end{longtable}%
}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\tablerow}[4]{%
  #1&#2&#3&#4 \\ 
  \hline
}


\newcommand{\myrow}[4]{%
  \addtocontents{stuff}{\tablerow{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}}
  #1&#2&#3&#4\\
  \hline%
}


\begin{document}


\listofstuff*

\section{Table 1}
\begin{tbl}
\myrow{1äöü€}{2}{3}{4}
\end{tbl}



\section{Table 2}
\begin{tbl}
\myrow{5}{6}{7}{8}
\end{tbl}

\begin{tbl}
\myrow{\foo}{6}{\foobar}{8}
\end{tbl}



\end{document}
```

[image]

**Update with page numbers**

```
\documentclass{article}
\RequirePackage{fontspec}


\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{environ}


\newcommand{\foo}{Some stuff}
\newcommand{\foobar}{Other stuff}

\makeatletter


\NewDocumentCommand{\@starttof}{smO{}}{%
  \begingroup
  \makeatletter
  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}{%
    \section*{#3}%
  }{%
    \section{#3}%
  }%
%  Table format may be changed%%%
  \begin{longtable}{|*{5}{p{2cm}|}}
    \hline\rowcolor[gray]{.8}%
    Column 1 & Column 2 & Column 3 & Column 4 & Page\\
    \hline%
    \endhead%
    \@input{\jobname.#2}%
  \end{longtable}
  \if@filesw
  \expandafter\newwrite\csname tf@#2\endcsname
  \immediate\openout \csname tf@#2\endcsname \jobname.#2\relax
  \fi
  \endgroup
}



\NewDocumentCommand{\listofstuff}{sO{Complete Table}}{%
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}{%
    \@starttof*{stuff}[#2]%
  }{%
    \@starttof{stuff}[#2]%
  }%
}



\NewEnviron{tbl}
{%
  \begin{longtable}{|*{4}{p{2cm}|}}
    \hline\rowcolor[gray]{.8}%
    Column 1 & Column 2 & Column 3 & Column 4\\\hline%
  \endhead%
  \BODY%
\end{longtable}%
}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\tablerow}[5]{%
  #1&#2&#3&#4&#5\\
  \hline
}

\newcommand{\myrow}[4]{%
  \addtocontents{stuff}{\tablerow{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}{\thepage}}
  #1&#2&#3&#4\\
  \hline%
}


\begin{document}


\listofstuff*

\clearpage

\section{Table 1}
\begin{tbl}
\myrow{1äöü€}{2}{3}{4}
\end{tbl}


\clearpage

\section{Table 2}
\begin{tbl}
\myrow{5}{6}{7}{8}
\end{tbl}

\begin{tbl}
\myrow{\foo}{6}{\foobar}{8}
\end{tbl}



\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: it seems so easy ;) Thank you. What do I have to do, if I want to put the page number in the `tof` as column 5?

Comment: @aronadaal: That's almost the same, just use another parameter for the page number -- this will be expanded at the time of using `\addtocontents` which is correct then, but do not use `\thepage` inside of `\tablerow`, since that command isn't expandable! See the 2nd update at the end!

Comment: Could you please extend your example with the usage of `hyperref`? I had a look at the question you linked, but there is too much `tex` code that I don't understand.

Comment: @aronadaal: Well, that's adding one feature after another one -- that's not how TeX.SX works

Comment: sure, but I thought that would be better than asking a new question with almost the same content. Anyway, I'm happy with the current solution. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @aronadaal: Actually, `hyperref` support is quite easy