# I need to display \listoffigures as a table

Tags: table-of-contents, report

[image]

I need to display the list of figures in a table format as shown in the figure.

What should I do to customize the `\listoffigures` command so as to obtain things in this format.

Comment: See my answer to this question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/263979/redefining-listoffigures-and-listoftables-as-tables. It requires some work to be done, however

Answer (score 2):

A slightly modified version from my answer to this question: [Redefining \listoffigures and \listoftables as tables](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/263979/redefining-listoffigures-and-listoftables-as-tables)

I used the command name `\tableoffigures` and did not touch `\listoffigures`.

The table is a `tabularx` with its longtable version from `ltablex`, so the table will break over pages if there are more figures than would fit in enumeration on the page.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[lmargin=1.5cm,rmargin=1.5cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{ltablex}
%\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{letltxmacro}
\usepackage{xparse}

\newif\ifhyperrefloaded


\newcounter{fullfigurecounter}
\newcounter{fulltablecounter}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter

\@ifpackageloaded{hyperref}{\hyperrefloadedtrue}{\hyperrefloadedfalse}


\providecommand{\theHtable}{}
\newcommand{\PhantomSection}{%
  \ifhyperrefloaded
  \phantomsection%
  \fi
}

\newcolumntype{A}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}

\def\@starttof#1#2{%
  \begingroup
  \makeatletter
  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
  % Table format may be changed%%%
  \renewcommand{\theHtable}{longtable.\theLT@tables}% Use a different Hyperref name for table due the \refstepcounter{table}- issue with longtable
  \bfseries%
  \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|p{3cm}|p{6cm}|A|}
    \multicolumn{3}{c}{}\tabularnewline
    \multicolumn{3}{c}{\Large \bfseries #2}\tabularnewline
    \multicolumn{3}{c}{}\tabularnewline
    \multicolumn{3}{c}{}\tabularnewline[0.5ex]
    \hline
    \large Figure No.  & \large Title &  \large Page \tabularnewline
    \hline
    \endhead % Repeating head
    \@input{\jobname.#1}%  Input the ToF or ToT file 
    \tabularnewline
  \hline
  \end{tabularx}
  \setcounter{table}{0}%
  \if@filesw
  \expandafter\newwrite\csname tf@#1\endcsname
  \immediate\openout \csname tf@#1\endcsname \jobname.#1\relax
  \fi
  \endgroup
}


\newcommand{\tofiguresname}{\listfigurename}
\newcommand{\totablesname}{Tabellenverzeichnis}


\newcommand{\tableoffigures}{%
  \cleardoublepage
  \PhantomSection%
  \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\tofiguresname}%
  \@starttof{tof}{\tofiguresname}
}%


\newcommand{\tableoftables}{%
  \clearpage
  \PhantomSection%
  \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\totablesname}%
  \@starttof{tot}{\totablesname}%
}%


\def\temp@@a{figure}%
\def\temp@@b{table}%

\LetLtxMacro\captionpkg@caption\caption

\newcommand{\writetofline}[3]{%
  \ifnum\value{fullfigurecounter} > 1
  \tabularnewline
  \protect\hline
  \fi
  #1 & #2 & 
  \ifhyperrefloaded 
  \protect\hyperlink{figure.\thefigure}{#3}%
  \else
  #3%
  \fi
}

\newcommand{\writetotline}[3]{%
  \ifnum\value{fulltablecounter} > 1
  \tabularnewline
  \protect\hline
  \fi
  #1 & #2 &  
  \ifhyperrefloaded 
  \protect\hyperlink{table.\thetable}{#3}%
  \else
  #3%
  \fi
}


\RenewDocumentCommand{\caption}{som}{%
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}{%
    \captionpkg@caption{#3}%
  }{%
    \ifx\@currenvir\temp@@a
    \stepcounter{fullfigurecounter}%
    \else
    \ifx\@currenvir\temp@@b
    \stepcounter{fulltablecounter}%
    \fi
    \fi
    \IfValueTF{#2}{%
      \captionpkg@caption[#2]{#3}%
      \ifx\@currenvir\temp@@a
      \addtocontents{tof}{\writetofline{\thefigure}{#2}{\thepage}}%
      \else
      \ifx\@currenvir\temp@@b
      \addtocontents{tot}{\writetotline{\thetable}{#2}{\thepage}}%
      \fi
      \fi
    }{%
      \captionpkg@caption{#3}%
      \ifx\@currenvir\temp@@a
      \addtocontents{tof}{\writetofline{\thefigure}{#3}{\thepage}}
      \else%
      \ifx\@currenvir\temp@@b
      \addtocontents{tot}{\writetotline{\thetable}{#3}{\thepage}}%
      \fi
      \fi
    }%
  }%
}




\makeatother

\usepackage{pgffor}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\clearpage

\tableoffigures
\clearpage

\section{A section}


\foreach \x in {1,...,20} {%
  \begin{figure}
    \caption{Irgendein Bild \x}
  \end{figure}
  \begin{figure}
    \caption[Die Sonnenblumen \x]{Irgendein Bild}
  \end{figure}
}
\clearpage

\foreach \x in {1,...,6} {%
  \begin{table}
    \caption[A nice table \x]{A nice table}
  \end{table}
}

\clearpage

\foreach \x in {1,...,20} {%
  \begin{figure}
  \caption[Impressionen \x]{Impressions du Soleil}
  \end{figure}
}


\end{document}
```

[image]