# How to put the table of contents into a table

Tags: tables, table-of-contents

Can I define the style of table of contents by using table in LaTeX? I want to do book of abstract and start with time table of speakers. What should I do if I do not want to do it manually?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)  Since this is more than just a conceptual question, can you please provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) of what you have so far?  This will help us help you.

Comment: I've answered Something similar for `\listoffigures` and `\listoftables`. The approach must be changed, but is doable, of course: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/285450/31729

Answer (score 2):

There is an example in section 29. The TOC as a table of the [etoc manual](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/etoc). If you use acrobat reader pdf viewer and go to page 53 you will see an icon near top, clicking on it will allow copying the code. Don't engage into that if you don't understand LaTeX macros enough.

Here it is actually (took me a while to realize I could copy paster myself): (you need `\usepackage{hyperref}` and `\usepackage{etoc}`)

```
%% LaTeX2e file `etocsnippet-29-A.tex'
%% generated by the `filecontentsdef' environment
%% from source `etoc' on 2016/09/29.
%%
\begingroup
\etocglobaldefs % necessary for \etocname etc... to survive &

% observe the locations of the \\
\etocsetstyle{part}
  {}
  {\\\hline}
  {\strut\etocnumber &\bfseries\etocname&\etocpage }
  {}

\etocsetstyle{section}
  {}
  {\etociffirst{\etocifnumbered{\\\hline}{\\\hline\hline}}{\\}}
  {\etocnumber&\etocname &\etocpage }
  {}

\etocsetstyle{subsection}
  {}
  {\\}
  {&\makebox[1cm][c]{\etocnumber}%
    \parbox[t]{\dimexpr6cm-\tabcolsep\relax}{\sloppy\itshape\etocname\strut}%
   &\itshape\etocpage }
  {}

\etocsettocstyle
    {\hypersetup{hidelinks}%
     \begin{longtable}{|>{\bfseries}c|p{7cm}|r|}
     \hline
     \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{\Large\bfseries\strut\strut TABLE OF CONTENTS}%
     }
    {\\\hline\end{longtable}}

\etocsetnexttocdepth {subsection}

\tableofcontents
\endgroup
```

There is another simpler example on page 53:

```
%% LaTeX2e file `etocsnippet-29-B.tex'
%% generated by the `filecontentsdef' environment
%% from source `etoc' on 2016/09/29.
%%
\begin{center}
\etocsetstyle{section}
             {}
             {\etociffirst{\\\hline\hline}{\\\hline}}
             {\etocname & \etocnumber & \etocpage }
             {}

\etocsettocstyle
   {\hypersetup{hidelinks}\begin{tabular}{|p{4cm}|c|c|}\hline
    \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\bfseries Section}&
    \bfseries number&
    \bfseries page}
   {\\\hline\end{tabular}}

\etocglobaldefs % MANDATORY !!
\etocsetnexttocdepth{1}

\tableofcontents % \ref{toc:overview}
\end{center}
```