# List of figure in table format

Tags: table-of-contents

As normal way we do, we insert `\listoffigures` for List of figure. But right now I want list of figure display like this picture below. How can I do it?
[image]

Here is MWE, you can choose 1 picture from your PC for testing.

```
\documentclass[13pt, a4paper, reqno, oneside]{book}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}

\thispagestyle{empty}

\listoffigures

\newpage
\begin{figure}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{xxx.PNG}
  \caption{xxx}
  \label{fig:x}
\end{figure}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing 
elit.  Etiam lobortisfacilisis...
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: It is important which document class you use.

Comment: @MichaelFraiman I use \documentclass{book} but I think it had no effect on final results. Wait for me for making a short MWE :D

Comment: The packages customizing LoT, ToC etc. may not be fully compatible with `KOMA-script` classes. Please, always include an MWE.

Comment: @MichaelFraiman I have just updated MWE for this problems. Let's try :D

Comment: @MichaelFraiman: KOMA-script? There's no KOMA class involved as far as I can see

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/285450/31729 for example

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I posted this comment when no MWE was provided.

Comment: @MichaelFraiman: Interestingly you supposed KOMA then right from the start ...

Comment: @ChristianHupfer yeah, your solution is work well, thank you :D But I see the problems with table using longtable packet. Can you upgrade?

Comment: @Yuri: `I see problems with table using longtable`??? This is no useful statement. Which problems do you mean?