# how to create list of tables in multicolumn

Tags: tables, table-of-contents, multicolumn

the table I need

[image: the table i need]

All i need is, I need to redefine my **list of table** in latex, like in above image. but i couldn't able to create it.

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[lmargin=1.5cm,rmargin=1.5cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{biblatex}
\usepackage{import}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[English]{babel}
\usepackage{mathtools} 
\usepackage{amsbsy}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{ragged2e} 
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{graphic}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{epstopdf} %convert .eps to .pdf image
\epstopdfsetup{update}
\usepackage{caption} %figure caption
\usepackage[labelfont=bf,labelformat=simple,labelsep=space, skip=6pt,list=true,lofdepth=2]{subcaption} %subfigure caption
\usepackage{tikz} %drawlatex graphs
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{listings} 
\usepackage{slashbox} 
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{manfnt}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{letltxmacro}
\usepackage{xparse}

\addbibresource{biblio.bib}

\newcounter{fullfigurecounter}
\newcounter{fulltablecounter}

\makeatletter


\def\@starttof#1#2{%
    \begingroup
    \makeatletter
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
    % Table format may be changed%%%
    \begin{longtable}{|p{2cm}|p{6cm}|p{7cm}|}
%       \hline
        \multicolumn{3}{c}{}\tabularnewline
        \multicolumn{3}{c}{\Large \bfseries #2}\tabularnewline
        \multicolumn{3}{c}{}\tabularnewline
%       \hline
        \multicolumn{3}{c}{}\tabularnewline[0.5ex]
        \hline
        \large Table No.  & \large Title of the Table & \large Page No. \tabularnewline
        \hline
        \endhead % Repeating head
        \@input{\jobname.#1}%  Input the ToF or ToT file 
        \tabularnewline
        \hline
    \end{longtable}
    \setcounter{table}{0}%
    \if@filesw
    \expandafter\newwrite\csname tf@#1\endcsname
    \immediate\openout \csname tf@#1\endcsname \jobname.#1\relax
    \fi
    \endgroup
}

\newcommand{\tableoffigures}{%
    \cleardoublepage
    \@starttof{tof}{Abbildungs- und Quellenverzeichnis}
}%


\newcommand{\tableoftables}{%
    \clearpage
    \@starttof{tot}{LIST OF TABLES}%
}%


\def\temp@@a{figure}%
\def\temp@@b{table}%

\LetLtxMacro\captionpkg@caption\caption

\newcommand{\writetofline}[3]{%
    \ifnum\value{fullfigurecounter} > 1
    \tabularnewline
    \protect\hline
    \fi
    \figurename\ #1 & #2 & #3 
}

\newcommand{\writetotline}[3]{%
    \ifnum\value{fulltablecounter} > 1
    \tabularnewline
    \protect\hline
    \fi
    \tablename\ #1 & #2 & #3 
}


\RenewDocumentCommand{\caption}{somO{Eigene Darstellung}}{%
    \IfBooleanTF{#1}{%
        \captionpkg@caption{#3}%
    }{%
        \ifx\@currenvir\temp@@a
        \stepcounter{fullfigurecounter}%
        \else
        \ifx\@currenvir\temp@@b
        \stepcounter{fulltablecounter}%
        \fi
        \fi
        \IfValueTF{#2}{%
            \captionpkg@caption[#2]{#3}%
            \ifx\@currenvir\temp@@a
            \addtocontents{tof}{\writetofline{\thefigure}{#2}{#4}}%
            \else
            \ifx\@currenvir\temp@@b
            \addtocontents{tot}{\writetotline{\thetable}{#2}{#4}}%
            \fi
            \fi
        }{%
            \captionpkg@caption{#3}%
            \ifx\@currenvir\temp@@a
            \addtocontents{tof}{\writetofline{\thefigure}{#3}{#4}}%
            \else%
            \ifx\@currenvir\temp@@b
            \addtocontents{tot}{\writetotline{\thetable}{#3}{#4}}%
            \fi
            \fi
        }%
    }%
}

\makeatother

\usepackage{pgffor}
\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents
    \clearpage
    \tableoffigures
    \clearpage
    \tableoftables 
    \clearpage
    \chapter{A sample for multicol table of contents}
    \foreach \x in {1,...,3} {%
        \begin{table}
            \caption[A nice table]{A nice table}[Me!]
        \end{table}
    }
    
    \clearpage
    \foreach \x in {1,...,20} {%
        \begin{figure}
            \caption{Irgendein Bild}
        \end{figure}
    
        \begin{figure}
            \caption[Die Sonnenblumen]{Irgendein Bild}[Vincent van Gogh]
        \end{figure}
    }
    \clearpage
    
    \foreach \x in {1,...,3} {%
        \begin{table}
            \caption[A nice table]{A nice table}[Me!]
        \end{table}
    }
        \clearpage
    
    \foreach \x in {1,...,20} {%
        \begin{figure}
            \caption[Impressionen]{Impressions du Soleil}[Monet]
        \end{figure}
    }
    \begin{table}[h]
        \caption[List of $ \theta $ signature]{$\theta$ signature}\\
        \centering
        \begin{tabular}{|c|*{6}{c|}}
            \hline
            \backslashbox{$ \boldsymbol{\theta} $}{signature}& \textbf{1} & \textbf{2} & \textbf{3} & \textbf{4} & $ \boldsymbol{\cdots} $ & $ \boldsymbol{t} $\\ \hline
            \textbf{1} & 1 &    2 & 3&  4&  $ \ldots $ &    1+c \\
            \hline
            
            \textbf{4} &    5 & 6 &     \multicolumn{3}{c|}{$ \ldots $} & 7\\ \cline{4-5}
            \hline
            $ \vdots $ &    \multicolumn{6}{c|}{$ \ldots $} \\ \cline{2-6}
            \hline

        \end{tabular}
        \label{theta}
    \end{table}
    
%   \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: Can we assume that you know about `\listoftables`?

Comment: yeah i do, but i didn't get like in image..

Comment: I think this https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/285450/283727 may be, what you are looking for.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Redefining \listoffigures and \listoftables as tables](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/263979/redefining-listoffigures-and-listoftables-as-tables)

Comment: No, I didn't get the proper answer when i run the code which mentioned in the link you sent.

Comment: yeah i got the answer but another problem arose. anyway it helped me sir.. thank you..